# popup image and view large from existing img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, struts2

I have loaded files from server of different types in a jsp, now I want image files when clicked to popup, I know I can again request the server for data and popitup, what I want to know is is there any way to enlarge the existing image from img tag?
I have done some thing like this, and presently able to see thumbnails.

```
<s:iterator value="furls" var="file">
            <div id="img_holder">
                <img src="<s:property value="#file.url"/>" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/no_preview.png';" alt="" height="100" width="100"/>
                <span id="text"><a href="<s:property value="#file.url"/>"><s:property value="#file.name"/></a></span>
            </div>
</s:iterator>
```

thanks and regards

Comment: "enlarge the existing image from img tag?" by changing width and height i suppose?!

Comment: What is actual image dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Try this- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/pTARc/3/)

css

```
.scale {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    transition:all 2s;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        $('img').toggleClass('scale');
    });
});
```